# installing and using R-nvim plugin with nvim with vim-plug

Tags: neovim, plugin-vim-plug

This is an elementary question really, for which my apologies, but I have been using `vim-plug` as my plugin.

I usually have done the following:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" common develpment
Plug 'bluz71/vim-nightfly-colors'
Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
Plug 'jalvesaq/Nvim-R', {'branch': 'stable'}
Plug 'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp'
Plug 'jalvesaq/cmp-nvim-r'
call plug#end()
```

and which has worked, by and large.

However, the developmental branch plugin for `R.nvim` at https://github.com/R-nvim/R.nvim has the following installation instruction:

```
  {
    "R-nvim/R.nvim",
    lazy = false
  },
  "R-nvim/cmp-r",
  {
    "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",
    config = function()
      require("cmp").setup({ sources = {{ name = "cmp_r" }}})
      require("cmp_r").setup({ })
    end,
  },
```

But I can not figure out where and how to put such a snippet/chunk in. Any suggestions on what is no doubt an elementary question is very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I tried putting:

```
Plug 'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter', {'do': ':TSUpdate'}
Plug 'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp'
Plug 'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp'
Plug 'R-nvim/R.nvim'
Plug 'R-nvim/cmp-r' 

lua require("cmp").setup({ sources = {{ name = "cmp_r" }}})
lua require("cmp_r").setup({ })
```

but I get:

```
    Error detected while processing /home/username/.config/nvim/init.vim[5]../home/username/.vim/vimrcs/new-plugins.vim:
line   23:
    E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: module 'cmp' not found:
            no field package.preload['cmp']
            no file './cmp.lua'
            no file '/usr/share/luajit-2.1/cmp.lua'
            no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/cmp.lua'
            no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/cmp/init.lua'
            no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/cmp.lua'
            no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/cmp/init.lua'
            no file './cmp.so'
            no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/cmp.so'
            no file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.1/cmp.so'
            no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
    stack traceback:
            [C]: in function 'require'
            [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
    line   22:
    E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: module 'cmp_r' not found:
            no field package.preload['cmp_r']
            no file './cmp_r.lua'
            no file '/usr/share/luajit-2.1/cmp_r.lua'
            no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/cmp_r.lua'
            no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/cmp_r/init.lua'
            no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/cmp_r.lua'
            no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/cmp_r/init.lua'
            no file './cmp_r.so'
            no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/cmp_r.so'
            no file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.1/cmp_r.so'
            no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
    stack traceback:
            [C]: in function 'require'
            [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
Error detected which processing BugNewFile Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: Error executing lua: /usr/sha
re/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:25: BufNewFile Autocommands for "*"..FileType Autocommands for "*"..fun
ction <SNR>1_LoadFTPlugin[19]..script /home/username/.vim/plugged/R.nvim/ftplugin/r_rnvim.lua: Vim(run
time):E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua
93: no parser for 'r' language, see :help treesitter-parsers
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:93: in function 'add'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/query.lua:252: in function 'parse'
        /home/maitra/.vim/plugged/R.nvim/lua/r/send.lua:642: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/maitra/.vim/plugged/R.nvim/lua/r/run.lua:7: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/maitra/.vim/plugged/R.nvim/lua/r/config.lua:739: in function 'global_setup'
        /home/maitra/.vim/plugged/R.nvim/lua/r/config.lua:803: in function 'real_setup'
        /home/maitra/.vim/plugged/R.nvim/ftplugin/r_rnvim.lua:12: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:25: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:2
4>
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:1
0>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:25: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:2
4>
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:1
0>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:1
0>
```

I do not know what `cmp` is, however, `cmp-r` is installed.

Comment: It look to me that the `hrsh7th/nvim-cmp` module is not installed properly. You should have a `~/.config/nvim-data/plugged/nvim-cmp/lua/cmp/init.lua` file after the installation that the code is supposed to import.

Comment: How do I reinstall a plugin? Also, I only have a `~/.config/nvim/` directory, should I first create a `~/.config/nvim-data/` directory?

Comment: The `~/.config/nvim-data/` folder should be created by `vim-plug`. I'm testing on Windows. There could be small variation. I have tested the setup I describe in my answer and it seems to be fine. I suppose you should be close ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I am on linux. But how does one reinstall a plugin?

Comment: On Linux the file should be `~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/nvim-cmp/lua/cmp/init.lua`.

Comment: To reinstall a plugin you could. 1. Comment the corresponding line in your `init.vim` 2. Quit Neovim, 3. Run `:PlugClean` 4. Uncomment the corresponding line in your `init.vim` 5. Quit Neovim 6. Run `:PlugInstall` 7. Restart Neovim.

Comment: I don't have a `~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/nvim-cmp/lua/cmp/init.lua.` however, i do have a `~/vimfiles/plugged/nvim-cmp/lua/cmp/init.lua`

Comment: That should be enough :-) you should be able to run successfully `:lua require('cmp')` are you? Is R correctly installed on your system and on the path. Is the `R` command running smooth on a shell?

Comment: Yes, R has been running fine. The following is the output to `which R`: I get: `R is /bin/R
R is /usr/bin/R` The complaint in `nvim` appears to be when it meets the `lua` line.

Comment: Do you still have the same error message or did it change?

Comment: Is the `lua requier('cmp')`  successfull?

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Now updated with complete error messages. No change is apparent.

Comment: I see à treesitter error. Could you try the `:RM` Neovim command I suppose it should trigger some download and auto configuration.

Comment: I get a bunch of R commands Example: RSendAndOpenNewOne, etc on the screen, nothing is downloaded.And the errors are still there.

Comment: The file are loaded in another folder in my machine because of the `call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')` call. Maybe could you try the more standard: `call plug#begin()`. I started to test on Ubuntu and instead of the `RM` call to download the treesitter parser I had to run the `:Runtime` command. My installation of R on Ubuntu is not yet perfect and the plugin is not behaving perfectly but my error are in R and not anymore in the plugin.

Comment: Thanks @VivianDeSmedt Can I have two `call plug#begin()` and 'call plug#end` for different directories?

Comment: I don't know that sorry :-|

Comment: By trial and error, the answer appears to be no, @VivianDeSmedt

Answer (score 0):

These are [lazy](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim) plugin manager instructions.

From what I read it seems you need to install:

- `hrsh7th/nvim-cmp`
- `R-nvim/R.nvim`
- `R-nvim/cmp-r`

```
Plug 'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp'
Plug 'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp'
Plug 'R-nvim/R.nvim'
Plug 'R-nvim/cmp-r'
```

I would try the following `vimrc` configuration:

```lua
lua require("cmp").setup({ sources = {{ name = "cmp_r" }}})
lua require("cmp_r").setup({ })
```

Remark: On Windows for the plugin to work the following two packages must be installed:

- [R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/)
- [RTools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/rtools.html)

The following path must be in the path:

- Rtools (e.g. `C:\rtools43`)
- R.exe (e.g. `C:\R\bin\x64`)
- RTerm.exe (e.g. `C:\R\bin\x64`)